# Heroku python mange.py ... subcommand not registered

Tags: django, heroku

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

This does not work as of March 15th, 2015.

The "shell" subcommand after manage.py is not recognized. Nor are any other custom manage.py subcommands.

Comment: heroku run 'echo 1 2 3' outputs only 1

Comment: Same here. `heroku-toolbelt/3.42.42 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
heroku-cli/4.27.26-693efcb (amd64-darwin) go1.6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is fixed:
https://status.heroku.com/incidents/868